# Import Error while importing module from different directory

Tags: python

I have a project directory structure like below

```
|project 
|-__init__.py
 |-src 
  |- __init.py__
  |- features
   |- __init.py__
   |- clean_data.py
 |-notebooks 
  |- notebook.ipynb
```

[image]

The main directory is called project under which I have two directories- src and notebooks.

I want to import the module clean_data.py under features directory (which is under src) in my notebook.ipynb file.

I tried this:

```
from ..src.features import clean_data
```

since all directories are serving as package with init.py file in each of them.

But it throws an error. Have spent quite a lot of effort in trying to figure this out but not sure why I am getting the error. As per this article too, I seem to be accessing the module correctly

```
mportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-11fd29e06b4c> in <module>()
----> 1 from ..src.features import clean_data

ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: 3.7.8. Using a conda environment an opening a notebook in that environment and trying to import a module from a different directory

Comment: Have you tried using `from project.src.features import clean_data`?

Comment: yes. It then says no Module named project.

Comment: I have tried similar relative path in other projects and it works fine. I have no clue why this is not working this time. I have spent a lot of time to figure this out. No luck

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16981921/260313

Comment: one of the ans mentions that the script shouldn't be in same package directory. My jupyter notebook from where I am calling the script is in another directory in parent dir than where the module is. Module is under src package. Notebook is under notebooks dir. Its not in same package

Answer (score 0):

This is a part of my code, look at this:

```
from domain_pricing.domains import *
from domain_pricing.conversion_rate import *
```

I'm importing `domains.py` and `conversion_rate.py` from `domain_pricing` folder.

What you should do is:

```
from src.features import clean_data
from src.data import another_module
```

You do not need `.` or `..` as Unix-Based systems pathing directories. You need to call the folder directly.

Comment: what u r mentioning is absolute path. I have written a relative path. Both should work. None work for me. However if i use absolute path, then I would have to put whole path 

from project.src.features import clean_data

Have tried this also, doesn't work

Comment: That's what is working in my project, but including relative path for me didn't work. If that didn't work, then try importing `project.src.features` path. If none worked, I think I don't know more solutions. I shared my solution.